# How do i get the value of a textfield in html through ajax/jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, html

I have a textfield with a submit button as follows:

```
                <form id="keywordForm" action="r2/keyword_subscribe/" method="post">
                <input type="text" size="50" value="Enter a new keyword for rosebud to crawl!">
                </br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="send()"  />
```

Question is i want to retrieve the value of the text in that textfield in my views.py. Is there any way i can do that?

I have a jquery script on the top with the submit button.

```
$("#keywordForm").submit(function(){};
```

I need to know how to pass it in.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it with javascript:

```
<input id="myTextField" name="myTextField" type="text" size="50" value="Enter a new keyword for rosebud to crawl!">
```

And then:

```
var value = $("myTextField").value;
```

Now you have the value in that "value" variable.

Because you did not have the "name" attribute in the field it wasn't submitted to the server.  If you add it, that input will be sent to the server and you can get it in php like this:

```
$_GET['myTextField']
```

Comment: Depends what you want to do, if you only want the form to be submitted, then you don't need to do a thing with javascript, just be sure to have the "name" attribute for every input you want to have on the server side.

Comment: so @Nitzan how do i access it from my views.py?

Comment: oh, django, not php. My bad. you get it with *request.POST["input_name"]*

Comment: i see let me try it out first. Thanks anyways! :D will accept ur answer soon!

Comment: the input_name here would be?

Comment: Thats your call, you did not give the name attribute in your code, I called it 'myTextField'. It's the name you give to the input

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8229/discussion-between-stanwin-siow-and-nitzan-tomer)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you make your server call.
Anyway, you can get the value into a variable this way:

```
var myVal = $('#keywordForm input[type="text"]').val();
```

Maybe if you'll provide more info I can assist you further...

Cheers.

Comment: well it's supposed to be using a ajax call to call another method in my python file. So in my python file how do i read that variable?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python nor its way of doing AJAX, but usually there should be a server function that gets parameters, and you call it from JavaScript, and provide the value of myVal as one of the parameters of that function. Another way is to send a JSON object to the server function. If that's your case, just add a key-value combination to your JSON object (something like o.text = myVal), and look for that key-value on the server side, when you parse the JSON object.